# Change order of values in a column based on values of another column

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say that we have the following data frame. For each group of column id, if the order of column y is 'BB' and the next row is 'AA', then I want to change the order of values only on column x and only for this group of id.

| id | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | AA |
| 1 | 9 | AA |
| 2 | 13 | AA |
| 2 | 19 | BB |
| 3 | 11 | **BB** |
| 3 | 25 | **AA** |

Follows the expected output.

| id | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | AA |
| 1 | 9 | AA |
| 2 | 13 | AA |
| 2 | 19 | BB |
| 3 | **25** | **BB** |
| 3 | **11** | **AA** |

Answer (score 3):

#### `argsort`

`argsort` returns the positional slice that would sort your values.  So take them and apply it to other values.

```
df.groupby('id', group_keys=False, as_index=False).apply(
    lambda d: d.assign(x=d.x.to_numpy()[d.y.argsort()])
)

   id   x   y
0   1  10  AA
1   1   9  AA
2   2  13  AA
3   2  19  BB
4   3  25  BB
5   3  11  AA
```